# Doctrine2 - get group which hasn't hidden person

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, memberof

The first entity called `BUNDLE`

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection of \Akademie\Course\Course
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Akademie\Course\Course", mappedBy="bundles")
 */
private $courses;
```

The second entity is called `COURSE`

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection of \Akademie\Bundle\Bundle
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Akademie\Bundle\Bundle", inversedBy="courses")
 */
    private $bundles;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection of \Akademie\Course\CourseDate
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Akademie\Course\CourseDate", mappedBy="course")
 */
    private $courseDates;

/**
 * @var int
 * @Column(type="boolean")
 */
    private $hidden;
```

and the third is called `COURSEDATE`

```
/**
 * @var \Akademie\Course\Course
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Akademie\Course\Course", inversedBy="courseDates")
 * @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
    private $course;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Column(type="datetimetz", nullable=true)
 */
    private $beginDate;
```

I have parameter `course` and I need to get all `bundles`, which contains this `course`. What's more, all other `courses` in that `bundle` has to have `courseDate` newer than current date and can't be *hidden*. Otherwise I don't want to get this bundle. I hope it is clear now...

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `MEMBER OF` but i think you are better of with an `INNER JOIN`.

DQL:

```
SELECT group
FROM path\to\entity\Group group
INNER JOIN group.persons person
INNER JOIN person.city city
WHERE person.hidden = FALSE AND city.name = :name
```

QueryBuilder:

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('group')
    ->from('path\to\entity\Group', 'group')
    ->innerJoin('group.persons', 'person')
    ->innerJoin('person.city', 'city')
    ->where('person.hidden = FALSE')
    ->andWhere('city.name = :name')
    ->setParameter('name', $yourName)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I assumed that your person entity has an attribute called `hidden` and that your person-city relationship is bidirectional.

Comment: @MattBuk Is this solution working for you or is there anything missing?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Doctrine is not typical SQL. There would be great, if you write it with QueryBuilder.

Comment: @MattBuk What I have written is DQL not SQL. This is what doctrine uses but i have added the QueryBuilder solution as well. You have to ensure that all my assumed relations and properties are on your entities.

Comment: Ok, I'm really lost with Doctrine...Give me few minutes and I change my question to exactly same problem I'm solving now.

Comment: Now it's up. If you could say how to achieve result.